# getIntent().getStringExtra() is null when app is opened

Tags: android

In my android app, I'm sending my users a notification and when they click on that notification, it opens to a specific fragment in the MainActivity. The notification opens to that specific fragment only half the time. When the app is still in the background of the device, it opens to that specific fragment when the user clicks on the notification, but when the app is not in the background and the user opens it from the notification, that specific fragment is not opened.

The problem has to do with the string extra in the intent I pass with the notification, it is null.

This is inside my MainActivity's `OnCreate(...)`

```
String newAddedGamesFragment = getIntent().getStringExtra("FragmentFromNotification");

// NOTIFICATION CLICK
if (newAddedGamesFragment != null) {
    if (newAddedGamesFragment.equals("NewAddedReleases")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From notification");
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(mCurrentFragment).show(mNewlyAddedReleasesFragment).commit();
        mCurrentFragment = mNewlyAddedReleasesFragment;
        initFragmentFeatures(4);
    }
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Not found!!");
}
```

And here's how I pass my intent to the notification. The passed intent opens the MainActivity and defines a new string extra by the name of `FragmentFromNotification`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("FragmentFromNotification", "NewAddedReleases");
    PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Use this at your `PendingIntent` 
`PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)`

Comment: is this working for you?

Comment: Override onNewIntent(Intent intent) method and try to perform your logic inside this method

Comment: Are you using the firebase? If so, then are you getting/sending the values through `data` rather than `notification`?

Comment: Yes I'm using firebase and no I'm using notification to send the data, but i'm not sure if i'm using notification to receive, I'm using onMessageReceived